# Unable to get the value from the drop down from html to python program in flask

Tags: python, templates, flask

I fetch the data from Mysql and populate the values to my html form in a drop down menu.Once the user selects the option, the value which gets sent back is only the first word.
For eg. from the drop down , if I choose the value " This is fun " . the first word "This" is only getting passed back to the program.
This is for a python flask assignment
Code from program:

```
@app.route('/updateissue',methods=["POST"])
def updateissue():    
      if request.method=='POST':
         if request.form['submit-button'] == 'Update':
             upd1 = request.form.get("updname")
#             upd1 = request.form['updname']
             display(upd1)
             updname = request.form.get("updissue")
             display(updname)
             cursor = conn.cursor()
             cursor.execute('UPDATE issuedb set resolution = %s where issuename = %s', (updname,upd1))
             conn.commit()
             return render_template("close.html")

Code from template:
<div class="row">
                Choose Your Outstanding Issue from the below
            </div>
            <br></br>
            <div class="row">
                <form method="POST" action={{url_for('updateissue')}}>
                <SELECT name="updname" style="font-family:verdana">
                {% for j in upd %}
                <OPTION value={{j[0]}}>{{j[0]}}</OPTION>
                {% endfor %}
                </SELECT>
                <br></br>
                <textarea name="updissue" placeholder="Enter the Resolution"></textarea>
                <input type="Submit" name="submit-button" value = "Update">
                </form>
            </div>
```

I need the entire value to be passed to my program that is " This is fun".

contents : This is a new issue which you need to find a solution

The route used is below

```
@app.route('/update')
def update():
      cursor = conn.cursor()
      cursor.execute('SELECT issuename FROM issuedb where resolution is NULL')
      upd = cursor.fetchall()
      return render_template("update.html", upd=upd)
```

Basically I read the values from the database and populate them to a SELECT clause.Once the user selects the value from the drop down , I send the selected value back to the program for further processing.

Sorry still face the same issue. It is not pulling the whole string.infact while coding just j instead of j[0], the single quotes also gets displayed in the drop down.

It does display the whole string "This is a new issue which you need to find a solution" as such.I see no issues here.

Since I read from the database to populate the drop down combo box, there are multiple values to be displayed on the drop down box.So, I have to use the %for loop to populate these values in the drop down box.When i tried to use your code , all the individual values were getting listed on the same row.
This is the input screen
[image]

Hope you are able to see the screen. The user has to select any of the the 3 values from the drop down.when the second and third row is selected , only the first word is being passed to the program.For eg.when I choose "This is a new issue...." , the value "This" only gets sent back to the program. Hope this helps.

These are the values which gets dispalyed in upd as required by you.
(('f',), ('this is a new issue which you need to find resolution',), ('issuessssss are there',))

Thanks for being so much patient and meticulously following on this.Your code works and I am done. Thanks much and very much appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your html attribute `value` does not accept an argument with words separated by spaces. You would need to enclose it all in quotes as shown:

```html
{% for j in upd %}
  <OPTION value="{{j[0]}}">{{j[0]}}</OPTION>
{% endfor %}
```

Without the quotes around `{{j[0}}`, the option's value attribute would only recognise the first word.